# Javadoc warning being shown while generating the package

Tags: java, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin

I'm working on the javadocs of a project, fixing all the errors and warnings that Javadoc shows.. But after fixing most of them, there are just this one that is being shown for some reason that I can't imagine.

```
4 warnings
[WARNING] Javadoc Warnings
[WARNING] C:\Users\magno\Documents\Globalmentor\Globalmentor's work\marmot\src\main\java\com\globalmentor\marmot\MarmotSession.java:100: warning - Tag @see: can't find getResourceKit(Repository, URFResource, Capability...) in com.globalmentor.marmot.MarmotSession
[WARNING] C:\Users\magno\Documents\Globalmentor\Globalmentor's work\marmot\src\main\java\com\globalmentor\marmot\MarmotSession.java:140: warning - Tag @see: can't find getResourceKit(Repository, URFResource, Capability...) in com.globalmentor.marmot.MarmotSession
[WARNING] C:\Users\magno\Documents\Globalmentor\Globalmentor's work\marmot\src\main\java\com\globalmentor\marmot\MarmotSession.java:166: warning - Tag @link: can't find getResourceKit(Repository, URFResource, Capability...) in com.globalmentor.marmot.MarmotSession
[WARNING] C:\Users\magno\Documents\Globalmentor\Globalmentor's work\marmot\src\main\java\com\globalmentor\marmot\MarmotSession.java:140: warning - Tag @link: can't find getResourceKit(Repository, URFResource, Capability...) in com.globalmentor.marmot.MarmotSession
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\magno\Documents\Globalmentor\Globalmentor's work\marmot\target\marmot-0.5.1-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 33.921 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-10-21T10:03:11-02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 29M/412M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The problem is: These references are on the same class than the method, and even Eclipse suggests them when I start writing the references, does anybody know anything else that could give me this warning?

Here is the javadocs that shows the warning:

```
/**
 * Determines if there exists resource kit appropriate for the given resource supporting the given capabilities.
 * @param repository The repository in which the resource resides.
 * @param resource The resource for which a resource kit should be returned.
 * @param capabilities The capabilities required for the resource kit.
 * @return <code>true</code> if there exists a resource kit to handle the given resource with the given capabilities, if any, in relation to the resource.
 * @see #getResourceKit(Repository, URFResource, Capability...)
 */
public boolean hasResourceKit(final Repository repository, final URFResource resource, final Capability... capabilities);

/**
 * Retrieves a resource kit appropriate for the given resource statically if possible, without further resource lookup. This method locates a resource kit in
 * the following priority:
 * <p>
 * The first resource kit supporting the resource content type determined by:
 * </p>
 * <ol>
 * <li>The given content type, if any.</li>
 * <li>The content determined if possible by {@link #getExtensionContentType(String)} from the resource URI extension.</li>
 * <li>The resource description is retrieved as a last resort and the resource kit is determined by delegating to
 * {@link #getResourceKit(Repository, URFResource, Capability...)}.</li>
 * </ol>
 * @param repository The repository in which the resource resides.
 * @param resourceURI The URI of the resource in the given repository.
 * @param contentType The type of content the resource contains, or <code>null</code> if unknown.
 * @param capabilities The capabilities required for the resource kit.
 * @return A resource kit to handle the given resource with the given capabilities, if any, in relation to the resource; or <code>null</code> if there is no
 *         registered resource kit with the given capabilities in relation to the resource.
 * @throws ResourceIOException if an error occurred retrieving a description of the resource kit.
 * @see #getResourceKit(Repository, URFResource, Capability...)
 */
public RK getResourceKit(final Repository repository, final URI resourceURI, final ContentType contentType, final Capability... capabilities)
        throws ResourceIOException;

/**
 * Retrieves a resource kit appropriate for a MIME content type. This method should only be used for special-purpose functionality; when accessing resources
 * {@link #getResourceKit(Repository, URFResource, Capability...)} should normally be used instead.
 * @param contentType The type of content the resource contains.
 * @param capabilities The capabilities required for the resource kit.
 * @return A resource kit with the requested capabilities to handle the given content type, or <code>null</code> if no appropriate resource kit is registered.
 */
public RK getResourceKit(final ContentType contentType, final Capability... capabilities);
```

---

And here is the method that's being referenced in the javadocs above, it's from the same class:

```
/**
 * Retrieves a resource kit appropriate for the given resource. This method locates a resource kit in the following priority:
 * <ol>
 * <li>The first resource kit supporting the resource content type determined by {@link #determineContentType(URFResource)}.</li>
 * <li>The first resource kit supporting one of the resource types.</li>
 * <li>If the resource has a collection URI, the default collection resource kit.</li>
 * <li>The default resource kit.</li>
 * </ol>
 * @param repository The repository in which the resource resides.
 * @param resource The resource for which a resource kit should be returned.
 * @param capabilities The capabilities required for the resource kit.
 * @return A resource kit to handle the given resource with the given capabilities, if any, in relation to the resource; or <code>null</code> if there is no
 *         registered resource kit with the given capabilities in relation to the resource.
 * @see #determineContentType(URFResource)
 */
public RK getResourceKit(final Repository repository, final URFResource resource, final Capability... capabilities);
```

Since the project is public, here is a link for the pull request of what I've done for fixing the javadocs: [Bitbucket - Globalmentor's Project: MARMOT-5](https://bitbucket.org/globalmentor/marmot/pull-requests/2/marmot-5-fixed-javadoc-errors/diff)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is actually related to the fact that `Capability` is a **static inner class**, there are many know issues in the javadoc tool with inner classes, to workaround this problem you should **prefix it with its outer class** which is `ResourceKit` in your case.

So simply replace this

```
@see #getResourceKit(Repository, URFResource, Capability...)
```

with this

```
@see #getResourceKit(Repository, URFResource, ResourceKit.Capability...)
```

and this

```
{@link #getResourceKit(Repository, URFResource, Capability...)}
```

with this

```
{@link #getResourceKit(Repository, URFResource, ResourceKit.Capability...)}
```

Comment: I really thought it was only about the method, thank you for pointing me out, it will help me to other situations like this in the future.